# Given $ \det A=2$ and $3I+2A=A^2$; how to find $\det(3I+A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix with $\det (A)= 2 $ and $3I + 2A= A^2$. 
>   Find $\det(3I+A)$.

I know the final answer is **16** according to the book, but I can not find a way to solve the question.
Here is how I tried to simplify the question:

$$3I + A= 3I + 2A - A = A^2 - A = A(A-I)$$

so we can say: $$\det(3I + A)= \det(A).\det(A-I)$$

But I can not find the value for $\det(A-I)$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: expand this : $\det\left((A-I)(A+I)\right)$ and use $\det (AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: Please do not delete your old questions. Instead, you can edit them to add context to your question. In addition, someone has edited your post for [MathJax](/math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), so please do not reverse the edit.

Comment: The conditions of this question are impossible, at least if the field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Since $A^2-2A-3I=0$, the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1$ and $3$, but there’s no way to form a product of these that equals $2$.

Comment: @Mary.M- Please say the source of problem! (book, lecture, preprints ,...). maybe $\det A=2$ is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$(3I+A)^2 = 9I + 6A + A^2 = 3(3I+2A) + A^2 = 4A^2$$

Edit: This implies

$$\text{det}(3I+A)^2 = \text{det}(4A^2) = 4^3\text{det}(A)^2 = 256$$

so the determinant must be one of $\pm 16$.

Comment: Notice that $\det(4A^2)=4^3\det(A^2)$.

Comment: @C.F.G. you're absolutely right, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 5):

Let it be clear : No matrix $A$ exists with these constraints.

Indeed, if one assumes that $V \neq 0$ is such that $AV=\lambda V$, then applying relationship $A^2-2A-3I=0$ to this vector $V$, one gets

$$\lambda^2 V-2\lambda V-3V=0 \iff \lambda^2-2\lambda-3=0$$

Therefore, the only possible eigenvalues are : $\lambda = -1$ or $3$.

Thus, the different possibilities for the spectrum of $A$ are :

$(-1, -1, -1), \ (-1, -1, 3), \ (-1, 3, 3), \ (3, 3, 3), \ \ \tag{1}$

But the determinant is the product of eigenvalues, and none of the four products issued from (1) is equal to $2$.

Comment: This is same thing i'am thinking about.

Comment: Note that the matrix could exist over fields of characteristic $3,$ $5$ or $11.$  In any case, though, this seems like a case of a problem-writer changing someone else's problem without comprehending the math behind it (which happens far too often)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\det(A-I)\det(A+I)&=\det\left((A-I)(A+I)\right)\\
&=\det (A^2-I)\\
&=\det (2A+2I)=2^3\det(A+I)
\end{align}
where in former equality we used from assumption. So if $\det(A+I)\neq 0$ then 
$$\det(A-I)=2^3$$
and so $\det(A) \det(A-I)=2\times 8=16$.

Comment: It is not possible to assume that $\det(A+I)\neq0$ because $-1$ has to be an eigenvalue of $A$...

Comment: @JeanMarie In light of amd's comment to the question, we're arguing about literally nothing here, but...  A priori there's nothing stating that $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A.$  However, we can show that if $-1$ isn't an eigenvalue, then $A=3I,$ which gives $\det(A+3I) = 216,$ which as this contradicts the computation given in CFG's answer, shows that $-1$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: can we guess the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ from the given polynomial?